# Rails and ASP.NET MVC when to use each?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc

we have a mixed development environment using ASP.NET MVC and Ruby on Rails. We have come from a purely C# / ASP.NET background, but now have some rails experience and we love both. Problem is deciding at the beginning of a project which one to use can sometimes be tricky.

Any tips for how to explain to the non technical members of our company and our clients why we would chose one over the other for various projects?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I guess I had not made the question clear enough really. I was trying to get an idea of how people are choosing which platform to use in which situation, and only added the "explain to non techs" part as a secondary request. 

I am fully aware of the reasons a client may request the MS solution over the open source solution or the other way around. I personally hate the "MS sucks" developer response as this is usually baseless when it comes to web apps. Especially MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Deployment? Rails is interpreted, ASP.NET MVC requires compiling.
- Speed? One's bound to be faster than the other, I'm assuming (although I cannot be certain) that ASP.NET MVC would be slightly faster as its compiled.
- Platform? ASP.NET MVC obviously has to run in a Windows environment, whereas Rails could run on *nix/Windows/Mac
- Development time? You're all going to be more familiar with the constructs of one system over another meaning one will take you longer to develop in.  If speed of development is required, one will be preferable.

Comment: Mono allows running ASP.NET MVC on many non-Windows platforms.

Comment: Indeed, I wasn't aware of the current status of Mono though.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest if they are non-technical, why would it matter to them? It's pretty rare for a customer to come and ask for a specific technology, and it sounds like you would be picking for them. Then presumably they would trust you to pick the appropriate technology.

If you have to justify to management, I can see that mattering, though. I have developed mostly with Rails and a little with ASP.Net and I do have a favorite, in Rails. That said, I would just fall back on my default and then just tell them the requirement that requires me to jump to the other technology. They can probably understand most reasons, like the ones illustrated by [Kezzer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39693/kezzer).

Answer (score 0):

> Any tips for how to explain to the non
>   technical members of our company and
>   our clients why we would chose one
>   over the other for various projects?

If they're non-technical, I don't see why they would care.

However, you could just tell them Microsoft made ASP.NET MVC while Ruby on Rails was not made by Microsoft.

Or, for which ever one you choose, just tell them it gets the job done the fastest/easiest.

Giving them a good response would require them to be technical (performance, compiling, etc..).

Comment: "tell them Microsoft made ASP.NET MVC while Ruby on Rails was not made by Microsoft." yeah, and hear "Microsoft sucks!!!" or something like this. he can even tell them that RoR is made by guys who make basecamp and hear about how cool Basecamp is. Neither the first nor the second are correct reasons for chosing RoR, but they can left him no choise.

Comment: (about "RoR is made by guys who make basecamp" - I'm not sure it's true, but there is some relationship, isn't it?)

Comment: @ Valya: I'm assuming these people are non-technical and thus wouldn't say Microsoft sucks. They would also be more at ease to know that their coders will be using technology made by a global leader. I'm not saying ASP.NET MVC is better than RoR (or vise versa), but giving them any real answer to why you chose either over the other would entail them knowing more technical things.